# How can I disable some commands in SFTP?

Tags: sftp

How can I disable some commands in `SFTP` for my clients, like `ln` & `symlink`?

I've checked man sftp, but didn't find what I'm searching for.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: As Michael Hampton said, this doesn't make sense. The only thing I can think to do is disallow access to those commands with Linux [ACLs](http://www.tecmint.com/secure-files-using-acls-in-linux/) from the users that log onto your server via SFTP and/or, depending if you're running SFTP in a chroot jail, the specific user that is running SFTP.

Answer (score 4):

*You did not specify, what SFTP server are you using. I'm assuming the OpenSSH.*

The [`sftp-server`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server) (and the compatible `internal-sftp`) has the `-P` and `-p` switches to black/white list certain SFTP requests.

You can use them to disallow the `symlink` requests:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -P symlink
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What did you try? What does not work? What does it do instead? What version of OpenSSH are you using?

Comment: Doesn't work a specific user as it is not usable in a Match block

Comment: @ErdalG. You are right. I've removed that part. You can use `ForceCommand` though (but that would disallow shell access, what you actually want to do anyway probably, if you want to limit what user can do).

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass args to the sftp command when using `ForceCommand`, not `Subsystem`. If you do what the other answer says, the `-P` arg will be silently ignored!

The correct way:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

ForceCommand internal-sftp -P symlink
```

(you possibly also want to put a `Match` block around the second line)